# TypeError, gulp plugin run-sequence

Tags: gulp, плагин

Добрый день, прошу помощи. Второй день не могу справится с сложностью.

Планирую сделать задачу watch для отслеживания изменения файлов и параллельно задачи сделать синхронными используя run-sequence. 
Написал задачу watch в gulpfile, при ее вызове все в порядке, но как только изменяю файл получается ошибка, код файла и ошибки ниже.

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');
var prettify = require('gulp-prettify');
var scss = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence').use(gulp);
var cached = require('gulp-cached');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var errorHandler = function(error){
    gutil.log([
        '\n',
        'Error plugin:', error.plugin,
        '\n',
        'Error massage:', error.message,
        ''
    ].join('\n'));
};

gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return gulp
        .src('./build')
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(['./source/*.html', './source/pages/*.*'])
        .pipe(cached('html'))
        .pipe(plumber(
            errorHandler
        ))
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            path: './source/pages/includes'
        }))
        .pipe(prettify({
            indent_size: 2
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
            return file.basename != 'index.html' ? './build/pages' : './build';
        }));
});

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('./source/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(cached('style'))
        .pipe(plumber(
            errorHandler
        ))
        .pipe(scss.sync())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    global.watch = true;

    watch('./source/scss/**/*.*', function(){
        runSequence('scss');
    });
});
```

Код ошибки:

```
[10:09:16] Starting 'watch'...
(node:6324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: gulp.hasTask is not a function
```

Версии:

```
CLI version 1.2.2
Gulp: Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2
run-sequence: 1.2.2,
```

Comment: .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css')); убери точки с запятыми, не создавай кучу var все через запятую так красивее и  .src('./source/scss/style.scss') точки  .src('/source/scss/style.scss')

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, это на вкус и цвет. Точка с запятой - хороший тон. А много `var` визуально понятнее (лично мне).

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, попробую, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в `run-sequence` - обещают сделать поддержку gulp 4.* когда он выйдет из беты.

[issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3899)

Comment: спасибо. зря только мучался(

Comment: @Version8, Поставьте 3 gulp, демаю заработает если никто больше 4 гульп не требует